# How to Convert int value 20140401 to 'April 2014' in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is what I tried .....

```
declare @date varchar(8)

set @date = (select max(convert(varchar(10), fileextractperiod)) 
             from [info-CentralReturns-DEV].CentralReturns.FactCancer)

select CONVERT(varchar(10), cast(@date as DATE), 103)
```

Resulting output: `01/04/2014`

But I need output as `April 2014`

Comment: if you want a different format, then perhaps you should use something other than `103`, which is exactly what you're getting: dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Why don't you redesign your database so a date is a date?   Then you wouldn't need these shenanigans.

Comment: [You can see all available system-provided styles for `CONVERT` here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - unfortunately, SQL Server **2008** doesn't yet have the `FORMAT` command that's available in SQL Server **2012** to use any arbitrary format. I guess you'll have to do some manual coding here

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 only supports the [limited set of system-provided styles for `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - if none of those match your needs, you'll need to handle it yourself. SQL Server **2012** has a `FORMAT` function for this purpose..

So in SQL Server 2008, you could create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FormatDateMonthYear(@input DATE)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Year INT = YEAR(@input)

    DECLARE @MonthName VARCHAR(15) = DATENAME(MONTH, @input)

    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(50)
    SET @Result = @MonthName + ' ' + CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4))

    RETURN @Result
END
```

and then call it to get the format you need:

```
SELECT dbo.FormatDateMonthYear('2014-04-22')
```

and you should get

```
April 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(CHAR(4), @date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), @date, 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
DateName( month , DateAdd( month , cast(SUBSTRING(@date, 5, 2) as int), -1 ) )
+ ' ' + SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DATENAME(MONTH,@date)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(@Date))
```